# How do I send a message in a group chat in Skype with Skype4COM?

Tags: c#, skype, bots, skype4com

I've been trying to make a "Skype Bot" in C#. So far I've successfully been able to get it to work in one on one chats. I can't get it to work in group chats. Here's my source:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace SkypeBot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Skype skype;
        private const string trigger = "!"; // Say !help
        private const string nick = "Bot";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            skype = new Skype();
            // Use skype protocol version 7 
            skype.Attach(7, false);
            // Listen 
            skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);
        }
        private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
        {
            if (TChatMessageStatus.cmsRead == status)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (msg.Body.IndexOf(trigger) == 0 && TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived == status)
            {
                // Remove trigger string and make lower case
                string command = msg.Body.Remove(0, trigger.Length).ToLower();

                // Send processed message back to skype chat window
                skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " + ProcessCommand(command));
                IChat ichat = skype.get_Chat(msg.Chat.Name);
                ichat.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " + ProcessCommand(command));
            }
        }

        private string ProcessCommand(string str)
        {
            string result;
            switch (str)
            {
                case "help":
                    result = "Sorry no help available";
                    break;
                case "date":
                    result = "Current Date is: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
                    break;
                case "time":
                    result = "Current Time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                    break;
                case "who":
                    result = "I am Bot, a magical Skype robot!";
                    break;
                case "moon":
                    result = "(moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) (moon) ";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "Sorry, I do not recognize your command";
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Where it sends the processed message I get the error "No overload for method 'SendMessage' takes 2 arguments".

However when I use:

```
skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " + 
      ProcessCommand(command));
```

It works perfectly, but not in group chats. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 23):

Try to use

```
msg.Chat.SendMessage("your message")
```

instead.

Best

Comment: @user1356292, since Vagaus post answers your question and it worked for you too. You should have accepted it as answer, or upvoted it at least. No offense, just a moral duty.